# Finding Sum of Prime Numbers between interval (C++ program doesn't work for large numbers)

Tags: c++

My code is below. it works perfectly while the interval in not very big. However whenever I go over a million the program stops. for instance for interval 2 to 2000000 the sum of primes should be 142913828922 (from the back of the book) whereas my application shows 1179908154. can someone please point out where have I gone wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#define BELOW 2000000;

using namespace std;
bool isPrime(int num)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(num); i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            ;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < BELOW i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            sum = sum + i;
            printf("sum: %ld\n", sum);
        }
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int` and `long` can only hold numbers so big.

Comment: The maximum value that a `long` can hold is 2147483647. Obviously your desired result is larger than that. You'll have to use the appropriate data type.

Comment: Since you want to check whether numbers are prime, they are certainly positive. You can use `unsigned` variables to double the maximum value, though to solve your problem you really have to use a "longer" type.

Comment: Extra semicolon in a macro, being used to separate for condition and update parts.  Really?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are dealing with is [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

`(signed) long` can on most machines have values between `-2147483647` and `2147483647`.

You should use larger data type, I would suggest `unsigned long long`, which, on most machines, can hold values between: `0` to `18446744073709551615` (on at least 64 bits) or `uint64_t` type.

Comment: `uint64_t` is not more portable. `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to have at least 64 bits. There is no guarantee that there exists a type with *exactly* 64 bits. And of course, having more bits doesn't hurt here. Types like `uint64_t` should be restricted to the rare applications where the exact bit size matters.

Comment: You could also choose to use `uint64_fast_t` or `uint64_least_t` but they're ugly and hardly ever used. It's pretty rare for a platform to support an integer type larger than 64 bits but not support an integer type of exactly 64 bits. Also keep in mind that some people consider using specific integer sizes a good practice - that way the code won't behave differently on different platforms. For example, Java and .NET fixed the sizes of integer types regardless of the underlying platform, and this is likely one of the rationales (though I'll admit that I don't have a citation for that ready).

Answer (score 1):

You should replace all occurrences of 'int' and 'long' with 'uint64_t'